# Accessing Common Coroutine Rule From All Modules - Android Unit Test

Tags: android, junit, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing

I have a `TestWatcher` class implementing `TestCoroutineScope` interface as follows:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(private val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()) :
TestWatcher(),
TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher) {
    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        cleanupTestCoroutines()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

This is used to provide Loopers to `ViewModelTest`s using kotlin coroutines, for example:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class BlaViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val coroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @MockK
    lateinit var blaUseCase: BlaUseCase

    private lateinit var blaViewModel: BlaViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        blaViewModel = BlaViewModel(blaUseCase)
    }

    @Test
    fun testBla_Positive() {
        coEvery {
            blaUseCase.execute(any()).await()
        } returns Resource.Success(Bla("data"))

        blaViewModel.blaLiveData.observeForever {}
        blaViewModel.bla()

        assert(blaViewModel.blaLiveData.value != null)
        assert(blaViewModel.blaLiveData.value is Resource.Success)
        assert((blaViewModel.blaLiveData.value as? Resource.Success)?.value?.data == "data")
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can only access `MainCoroutineRule` from the same module test directory where `BlaViewModelTest` remains.

If I move `MainCoroutineRule` to a test directory in a common module, let's say `base`, `BlaViewModelTest` cannot access `MainCoroutineRule` during test run time failing at the end. There is no problem in compile time.

I tried to move `MainCoroutineRule` into main package of `base`, but it forced me to implement test libraries in project which is not a good approach from my point of view.

I don't want to duplicate `MainCoroutineRule` for all modules, I want to access it from a common source.

Any approaches will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> If I move `MainCoroutineRule` to a test directory in a common module, let's say `base`, `BlaViewModelTest` cannot access `MainCoroutineRule` during test run time failing at the end. There is no problem in compile time.

Test sources won't be available in consumer modules. I don't know why they're available at compile-time and why the IDE doesn't complain about it, but I definitely experienced the same thing.

To solve this you can create a separate test-only module (e.g. `base-testing`, `test-utils`). The rule should be part of the module's normal sources (`src/main`, **not** `src/test`). Then you can include that module as `testImplementation` in your consumer modules.